# Is the carrier name returned in iOS a network carrier name or a sim carrier name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-telephony

I need to know if iOS returns the sim operator name, or the network operator name.

In iOS, I'm accessing carrier informations the following way :

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier* carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider;
NSString* iOSCarrierName = carrier.carrierName;
```

In Android, There are 2 explicit methods to get one or the other :

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
String networkCarrierName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
String simCarrierName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo/1616900-subscribercellularprovider?language=objc) says that `subscriberCellularProvider` is

> A CTCarrier object that contains information about the user’s home cellular service provider—that is, the provider with whom the user has an account.

So it is definitely the sim operator name. [More info](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony/ctcarrier?language=objc)